# What is an easy way to append or prepend a single value to an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I need to prepend a single value to an IEnumerable (in this case, `IEnumerable<string[]>`). In order to do that, I'm creating a `List<T>` just to wrap the first value so that I can call `Concat`:

```
// get headers and data together
IEnumerable<string[]> headers = new List<string[]> {
    GetHeaders()
};
var all = headers.Concat(GetData());
```

Yuck. Is there a better way? And how would you handle the opposite case of appending a value?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I wrote custom extension methods to do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item)
{
    foreach (T i in source)
        yield return i;

    yield return item;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item)
{
    yield return item;

    foreach (T i in source)
        yield return i;
}
```

In your scenario, you would write:

```
var all = GetData().Prepend(GetHeaders());
```

As chilltemp commented, this does not mutate the original collection. In true Linq fashion, it generates a new `IEnumerable<T>`.

***Note:*** An eager null argument check is recommended for `source`, but not shown for brevity.

Comment: Nice! I have some in my library just like those.

Comment: Elegant.  It should be noted that this will return a new IEnumerable<T> by enumerating the existing collection.  It does not actually append/prepend the original collection.

Comment: Note that Append and Prepend are builtin in .NET since 4.7.1. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59643531/1248177)

Answer (score 8):

Use the [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) extension method.  For appending values instead of prepending, you'd just call `Concat` in reverse.  (ie: `GetData().Concat(GetHeaders());`)

If `GetHeaders()` returns a single string array, I'd personally probably wrap it in a single element array instead of a list:

```
 var all = (new[] {GetHeaders()}).Concat(GetData());
```

Comment: GetHeaders() returns `string[]`, GetData() returns `IEnumerable<string>`. Did you read my question?

Comment: @Gabe: This will work with string[] and IEnumerable<string> - arrays implement IEnumerable<T>.  If your string[] is **string**, however, things are a bit different.  Your question wasn't incredibly clear here.

Comment: @Gabe: I'm still not sure exactly what you want - I put in another edit, that shows you how to preserve all elements as arrays...

Comment: @Reed and my comment was wrong - GetData() returns `IEnumerable<string[]>`, sorry for the confusion. You should be able to infer the types from my question, though.

Answer (score 1):

Rx contains StartWith method that prepends value to sequence. Also Return can wrap value as sequence so it can be appended via Concat.

```
        var c = new[] {4};
        var c1 = c.StartWith(1, 2, 3);
        var c2 = c1.Concat(EnumerableEx.Return(5));

        c2.Run(Console.Write); // 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a helper method that creates a sequence out of a single item:

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> One<T>(T item)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}

...
//prepend:
EnumerableExt.One( GetHeaders() ).Concat( GetData() );

//append:
GetData().Concat( EnumerableExt.One( GetHeaders() );
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest way for .NET 4.7.1 and newer is to use the side-effect free [`Prepend()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7) and [`Append()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.8).

Example

```
// Creating an array of numbers
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

// Prepend and Append any value of the same type
var results = numbers.Prepend(0).Append(4);

// output is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results ));
```